# Defining JPA Default Table Qualifier

Tags: jpa, playframework

All of my tables (MSSQL) use a schema/qualifier/prefix (e.g., `abc.Table1`, `abc.Table2`). This qualifier is the same for all of the tables and I would like to specify it as a default to JPA so that I do not need to annotate each class with a custom name string.

This can be done with XML configuration like so:

```
<entity-mappings>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema name="abc"/>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

However, I am using the Play Framework where JPA configuration is done in the webapps's `application.conf` file. Is it possible to declare this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add `hibernate.default_schema=abc` to your `application.conf`? Play should support setting additional Hibernate properties this way.

Comment: Ah I didn't know I could use hibernate stuff directly as well! Thank you.